# Using messengerApi in visual studio (c#) in any windows, compatibility issue

Tags: c#, api, exception, windows-xp, msn

I'm Trying to develop a project that interacts with Live Messenger (8.5, 9.0 and higher)
I can't get it to work in windows XP, whenever i try to instantiate a **MessengerClass** (available in the **messengerAPI**) it gives me an exception, however, in windows vista, this error doesn't happen (*same exact code*, tested in more than one XP and more than one Vista machine).
I've read in forums that this issue is due to a security update microsoft has released in november 2008, but i haven't found a solution (though i'm not quite sure about it).
Has anyone ever had this problem ? any solution ? workarounds ?

Comment: I get: "outofmemory exception" Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {B69003B3-C55E-4B48-836C-BC5946FC3B28} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8007000e.                                       I've searched it and it's not specific.. kinda general, a lot more people have had this, and i believe this error is related to the system itself rather than my code, because it works flawlessly in vista. thanks for helping!

Comment: http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/3894/exception.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found in a forum someone that has got the old discontinued version of MessengerAPI for desktop applications and made it fit into newer live messenger clients by editing the api itself and made it available in a [link](http://forums.fanatic.net.nz/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=850) *(note that as of July 21, 2011, this link is broken)*.

You just have to run TLBIMP.EXE from the command console in visual studio:

```
tlbimp [path]\MSNMessengerAPI.tlb
```

This will create a .dll in the same folder as the original .tlb file. You can import it as a reference in Visual Studio and use it right away.